# Render issues when resetting mouse position inside of a switch case with sfml

Tags: c++, switch-statement, mouse, render, sfml

I'm making a basic breakout game using SFML in order to familiarize myself with C++ (moving up from C). Inside the game loop, I've placed an event poll that leads to a switch statement. When the mouse is moved, the switch-case will retrieve the mouse xy change and move the paddle accordingly, like so:

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                switch (event.key.code)
                {
                    case sf::Keyboard::Escape:
                        window.close();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
                paddle.move(sf::Vector2f((sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x - windowOffset.x) * sensitivity, 0));
                break;
        }
    }
    sf::Mouse::setPosition(windowOffset, window);
    window.clear();
    window.draw(paddle);
    window.display();
}
```

Now, that works just fine and dandy, *but* I'm resetting the mouse position to the center of the window on *every* loop, which isn't necessary if the mouse hasn't moved. So, I tried moving `sf::Mouse::setPosition()` into the switch statement, underneath `paddle.move`, like so:

```
case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
    paddle.move(sf::Vector2f((sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x - windowOffset.x) * sensitivity, 0));
    sf::Mouse::setPosition(windowOffset, window);
    break;
```

However, when I rebuild the project, I now get a blank white window.
So, my question is: *What's causing this to happen?*

edit(minimal complete code)

```
int WinMain()
{
    sf::Vector2i windowRes(700, 900);
    sf::Vector2i windowOffset(350, 450);
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    sf::RectangleShape paddle;
    paddle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(150, 20));
    paddle.setOrigin(350, 0);
    paddle.setPosition(350, 825);
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowRes.x, windowRes.y), "Breakout", sf::Style::Default, settings);
    window.setMouseCursorVisible(false);
    sf::Mouse::setPosition(windowOffset, window);
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                switch (event.key.code)
                {
                case sf::Keyboard::Escape:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
                paddle.move(sf::Vector2f((sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x - windowOffset.x), 0));
                //sf::Mouse::setPosition(windowOffset, window);
                break;
            }
        }
        sf::Mouse::setPosition(windowOffset, window);
        window.clear();
        window.draw(paddle);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you use wrong configurations. Are you linking debug libs in release mode or the other way around?

Comment: @Lukas I just double checked, and that doesn't seem to be the issue. I've statically linked all the sfml library files accordingly for both release _and_ debug, and am building in debug mode as well. Furthermore, the issue resolves if I move `sf::Mouse::setPosition()` back out of the switch, and then do a full rebuild of the project. Whatever is happening _appears_ to be directly linked to the placement of `sf::Mouse::setPosition()` within the switch case. Thanks for the response, though!

Comment: When code acts different depending on the position of some code line, it usually is some heap or configuration issue. I'm sure that if you provided a complete and minimal example it would run just fine on my system.

Comment: @Lukas Alright, I've cobbled together a minimal example (and added it to my initial posted question), which still produces the same problem as the original code. I've left the `Mouse::setPosition` line inside the switch (where I encounter issues), but commented out. Line 42 contains the same line of code, which is where I am able to use it without error.

Answer (score 0):

So, through some tinkering, it seems that `sf::MOUSE::setposition()` generates an `event.type` of `sf::Event::MouseMoved`, which would be added to the event queue, causing an infinite loop.